# htaccess mask url without redirect

Tags: .htaccess

I have a domain on which I host a website at `http://design.maindomain.com/MDD/` and I also have an addon domain `addondomain.com`.

Can I make it so that when someone visits `addondomain.com/index.html` he will see `http://design.maindomain.com/MDD/index.html` but the URL in the address bar would still remain `addondomain.com/index.html`?

Comment: just configure a server alias in apache

Comment: You can do so by pointing same `DocumentRoot` in both domains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank is configurable in most Cpanels if not you should ask your host.

Comment: actually already found it in Cpanel but forgot to update this question.